# Why is my vhosts file interfering with my apache deployment?

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

When I enable my vhosts file (i.e. uncomment this line: `Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`) I am unable to reach localhost. I /am/ able to reach the last virtual host listed in my vhosts file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "/Users/achan/Sites/epwbst"
  ServerName epwbst                                                                                                  
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "/Users/achan/Sites/pxproj"
  ServerName pxproj
</VirtualHost>
```

Typing `pxproj` in my browser brings up the expected web content. But I am unable to reach `epwbst` or `localhost`. If I re-comment the vhost line in my httpd.conf, I am able to reach local host (i.e. "It works!") but obviously am unable to reach my virtual hosts. I don't know how to continue troubleshooting this.

**Why can't I reach `localhost` when I've got my vhosts turned on?**

OS: Mac OS X 10.7

Server version: Apache/2.2.21 (Unix)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you turn on vhosts, you must add localhost as a vhost. See my answer here: [Virtual host “Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server” on debian](https://serverfault.com/questions/260430/virtual-host-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server-on/394782#394782)

Comment: Thanks; I wonder if this is something new because in my previous encounters with apache I don't remember doing this.